# Custom SlidingTabs with Image and text

Tags: android

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html) and it works perfect, I mean the `SlidingTabs` works fine, and all is fine, but I'd like to add something like this :

[image]

I searched and people uses `actionbar.addTab()` but I'm not able to do this...

This is what they do :

```
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[i])
                     .setIcon(resources.getDrawable(ICONS[i]))
                     .setTabListener(this));
```

but I can't call this `addTab`...
I add tabs like this :

```
adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // TabsFixed
tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
  @Override
  public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });
tabs.setViewPager(pager);
```

Where `Titles` is a `String[]` and `Numoftabs` are the number of tabs that are shown.

How do I add an image above the title?

### EDIT

Now I've implemented the code that @cricket_007 gave to me and I face with this problem :

I'm trying to create the selector when you click on a tab change the color of the `ImageView` and the `TextView`, I did it but this is not clear code :

```
View View2= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
ImageView iconHome = (ImageView) View2.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
TextView textView = (TextView) View2.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.white));
iconHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
textView.setText("Manual");

View TabView2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_view,null);
ImageView iconIn = (ImageView) TabView2.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
TextView textViewIn = (TextView) TabView2.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
iconIn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
textViewIn.setText("Tab2");
```

But it should be automatically I mean when I launch the APP the first item on the tab stay selected (white image and text for example) and the rest gray(#ddd) but this is not working with that code...

Comment: ActionBar Tabs were replaced by a `TabLayout`, so the tutorial you linked to doesn't do `actionBar.addTab`

Comment: Plus, that tutorial is a bit outdated, so you might want to use [this new one on that site](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/12/tab-layout-material-design-support.html) instead

Comment: Doesn't look like it. I guess the author didn't want people to see the completely finished result.

Comment: And if I'm trying to add the last method (Image and TextView below) and want to when is selected one tab have one color and when not selected has other I have to create two drawables?

Comment: Two drawables and a selector, if I had to guess. Personally haven't made a custom tab layout before.

Comment: @cricket_007 See my edit please

Comment: I just removed the elevation and it works, trying to know how to create a selector with that... I'll edit the question

Comment: You may not need the selector based on what I am reading in the `onPageSelected` method. You just toggle the images of all the tabs to the proper one.

Comment: I saw also that method, but what do you mean that, every time onPageSelected is called change the image and text ?

Comment: Like with just the TextViews, the selector was needed to change the color, but when you have a custom View with both an image and text, I don't think a selector will be able to change the color, so you'll need to get the View of the tab at that position, and set the src of ImageView and foreground color of the TextView

Comment: And same with the TextView, right?

Comment: Yes, like I said in that those last few words, set the image resource and the foreground color of the TextView. There is an OnTabChangedListener (forget the exact name), that will allow you to know when a tab is selected or unselected. You could also use just a textview and use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` to set an image resource on a textview

Comment: could you post an answer with a simply example @cricket_007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some thinking about extensions to that [second tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/12/tab-layout-material-design-support.html) I linked to, I came up with this simplistic way to use a label and two images without requiring a custom layout for the tab.

Basically, doing something like the [ViewHolder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder), define this class inside the Activity.

```
private static class TabViewHolder {
    int selectedIconId, unselectedIconId;
    String text;

    public TabViewHolder(String text, int selectedIconId, int unselectedIconId) {
        this.text = text;
        this.selectedIconId = selectedIconId;
        this.unselectedIconId = unselectedIconId;
    }
}
```

Then, `onCreate` looks like so

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    setupTabLayout(tabLayout);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            TabViewHolder holder = (TabViewHolder) tab.getTag();
            if (holder == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ViewHolder for tab " + tab.getPosition() + " not set");
            } else {
                tab.setIcon(holder.selectedIconId);
            }

            // Make sure to bind the pages to the tabs
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition(), true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            TabViewHolder holder = (TabViewHolder) tab.getTag();
            if (holder == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ViewHolder for tab " + tab.getPosition() + " not set");
            } else {
                tab.setIcon(holder.unselectedIconId);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}
```

With `setupTabLayout` looking like this

```
private void setupTabLayout(TabLayout tabLayout) {
    TabViewHolder homeTabHolder = new TabViewHolder("Home", R.drawable.ic_home_white, R.drawable.ic_home_grey);
    TabViewHolder inboxTabHolder = new TabViewHolder("Inbox", R.drawable.ic_inbox_white, R.drawable.ic_inbox_grey);
    TabViewHolder starTabHolder = new TabViewHolder("Star", R.drawable.ic_star_white, R.drawable.ic_star_grey);

    final TabLayout.Tab home = tabLayout.newTab()
            .setText(homeTabHolder.text)
            .setIcon(homeTabHolder.selectedIconId) // set this as first selected
            .setTag(homeTabHolder);

    final TabLayout.Tab inbox = tabLayout.newTab()
            .setText(inboxTabHolder.text)
            .setIcon(inboxTabHolder.unselectedIconId)
            .setTag(inboxTabHolder);

    final TabLayout.Tab star = tabLayout.newTab()
            .setText(starTabHolder.text)
            .setIcon(starTabHolder.unselectedIconId)
            .setTag(starTabHolder);

    tabLayout.addTab(home);
    tabLayout.addTab(inbox);
    tabLayout.addTab(star);

    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.tab_selector));
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.indicator));
}
```

For me, the result looked like this on app launch

[image: home selected]

Then this when selecting the next tab

[image: inbox selected]

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you post the R.color.indicator, please?

Comment: I got it from the tutorial, I believe

Comment: The exact color I used was `#fe7e24`

Comment: Tried your code, works perfect when I click  on the item of the tab, but if I try to move the tabs sliding the finger it changes the tab but doesn't change the tab selector, you know why? with my old code it worked...

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The tab indicator changes for me both when I click the tab and swipe the pages. In order to get the pages to work, I had to add in `onTabSelected` the line that says `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition(), true);`

Comment: Nevermind now it's working perfect @cricket_007 thanks a lot mate :D